# Add a value to an JSON array

Tags: jquery, json, append

So I have an array that looks like this

```
[{"subbasinID":"1"},{"subbasinID":"2"}, etc....]
```

I need to add more values into each record. How do I ADD to an existing array so it might look something like this

```
[{"subbasinID":"1","test":"1","name":"john"},{"subbasinID":"2","test":"0"}]
```

I will know the name and value of the next group I need to add. I assume I have to identify which record I want and then append by finding the subbasinID. Not sure how! Thanks!

Comment: You actually want to extend an existing object (which is an element of array), but not to push new elements into this array. How exactly these elements should be altered?

Comment: "I will know the name and value of the next group I need to add" what does that mean?

Comment: So I set the array up so that I have about 100 subbasin. I then am going to loop through a bunch of data outside this array and append what I need inside this. So for instance, if I find out that subbasinID:1 has water in it, then I need to add water and its value to it. So it would look like "water":"12" within the subbasin:1.

Comment: My first array was built as a holder for much more information to be filled in. It is filling it in that is giving me issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a list(array) of objects. All you need is to iterate the object and add elements to it.

```
var t = [{"subbasinID":"1"},{"subbasinID":"2"}/*, etc....*/]
t[0]["name"] = "John";
```

Comment: and this will add John only to the first element (0)?

Comment: @jeynon Yes, if you want to add it to all the objects.. then you need to loop the array with a `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but adding to objects in JavaScript is pretty simple.  You can use jQuery `.each` if you like, but it's not necessary either:

```
for (var x = 0; x < arrayVar.length; x++) {
   arrayVar[x].test = test;
   if (name) {
      arrayVar[x].name = name;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The json object here is an Array.. So you can access the values like a 2D array and manipulate this..

```
 var json = [{"subbasinID":"1","test":"1","name":"john"},{"subbasinID":"2","test":"0"}]



  json[0]["test"] = "1" ;   OR   json[0].test = "1"

   json[0]["name"] = "john"

    json[1]["test"] = "0" ;
```

You can come up with a generalized approach once you know the names of the fields that you want to add..

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one by finding ID and add it.

```
var arr = [{"subbasinID":"1"},{"subbasinID":"2"}];

$.each(arr, function(i, arrVal)  {    
   if (arrVal.subbasinID === "1") {    
      arrVal.test = "1";
      arrVal.name = "john";
   }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really have a "JSON array" and not just a javascript array, the simplest is to

1. parse it into a javascript array
2. add your values
3. serialize it again as JSON

Like this :

```
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
obj[0]['test']='1';
...
str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

If you're not sure about the "JSON" term, I'd suggest you this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: I don't think he has a JSON string, I think he already has a JSON object available.  Not sure, though.

Comment: @ExplosionPills What does that mean, a "JSON object" ? If you mean there is probably no JSON at all involved, I suspect it too.

Comment: I guess I should just say "an object"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the splice function to add and remove items from a JSON array. The first 0 is the position of where you want to add (use 0 for the first position) and the second you specify if you want to remove an item.

```
dataArray.splice(0, 0,
{id: "7", name: "Douglas Adams", type: "comedy"});
```